# clarification on method overloading

Tags: java, string, overloading

I have this following code and I need some clarification regarding the *overloading* concept.

```
class Overload{
    static void print(Object o){
        System.out.println("object");
    }
    static void print(String s){
        System.out.println("string");
    }
    public static void main(String...args){
        print("Hello");
    }
}
```

when I execute this, the output is String. Eventhough `object` is the super class, why does it display `string` instead of `object`?

thanks in advance

Comment: https://blogs.oracle.com/mcimadamore/entry/testing_overload_resolution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rule in this case is:

> the more specific signature will apply

`String` is more specific than `Object`, that's why `print(String)` is used. For instance, try with `print(null)` in your `main`, you will see find out that such code will not even compile, since the compiler will have no way to distinguish whether `null` is a `String` or an `Object`

Check out [Oracle Overloading Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)

Answer (score 1):

Because when there is an exact match, during overloaded functions, JVM will not consider generalization. i.e it will look for the best fit to match the argument type. In this case "Hello" is an exact match to String type. Since `String` fits better in `String` than in `Object`. Hence it will not consider

```
static void print(Object o)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is called `string` print because you pass `"Hello"` which is `String` object.

`String` also extends regular `Object` but overloading calls also the most upper type.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, this version of overloaded method executes:

```
static void print(String s){
    System.out.println("string");
}
```

Since you are calling like this: 
`print("Hello");`

Data conversions happen only if and only if correct version of match is not found. And exact match is found for compiler.

Answer (score 1):

First `JVM` sees for the `print(String)`, if not found it searches for `print()` with argument of superclass of String. If still not found, then super-class of super-class of `String`. And this algorithm continues until there is `print(Object)`. Or reporting an error